# how to change two units into one in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to make this circle's stroke width the same as the rectangle's width. but Illustrator is measuring the circle stroke in points and the rectangle is 10 mm wide. so how can I make these two same in width?

Thank you[image]

Comment: You can change the units for strokes to mm [in Illustrator's preferences](https://imgur.com/UVizj2L)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type "10mm" directly into the stroke-width box for the circle (under the "Properties" tab).  The unit conversion is done for you automatically.

It's a very useful feature and actually works for many of Illustrator's various dialog boxes that accept measurements.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Drag your rectangle to the brushes panel and define it to be an art brush. See the definition dialog settings. Apply the new brush to your circle.

Comment: A brush is kind of overkill.. just set the stroke to 10mm.

Comment: @Scott it's overkill for known 10 mm width, it's perfect for general sameness without more knowledge of the width than "the rectangle is adjusted just now to have the right width"

Comment: uhm.. Illustrator will tell you the width, precisely, of any rectangle.

Comment: One day the questioner can remove the word "rectangle". This covers also some possibilities in that case.

Comment: Right.... and one day the user may want to make a pattern..... should your answer cover that as well? `:)` I don't think this is a "wrong" answer.. but it is an *absolutely, completely, unwarranted,* over use of brushes.

Comment: Thank you all. you people save naive like us. Thank you <3